# Format GPX.writeFeatures doesn't write feature nodes

Tags: openlayers, gpx

I'm attempting to generate a gpx from a LineString feature with ol/format/GPX.writeFeatures() but only get the gpx header:

```
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd" version="1.1" creator="OpenLayers"/>
```

with none of the feature's nodes.

As a test, I've added:

```
let gpx = new GPX();
console.log(features[0]);
console.log(gpx.writeFeatures(features[0]));
```

to the [GPX Data Example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/gpx.html) index.js in the displayFeatureInfo function.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `writeFeatures` expects an array, so you are missing a pair of `[]` brackets https://codesandbox.io/s/gpx-icdlt

Comment: Thank you so much! I had initially used just 'features' rather than 'features[0]', so not quite sure why that didn't work.